# Pulling from main breaks my development branch

Tags: git, github

I want to stop merging main into my development branch. (that how we were defined to work to keep history)
It causes many unwanted changes to my already nicely working branch, furthermore I want to keep my branch with all my commits as a point where I know all works. But main keeps progressing, and I keep merging it to me and solving awful conflicts on my private development branch that bring numerous bugs.
So, I thought I would stop and create a separate branch on main, and instead of merging main to me, I will merge my development branch to that branch. This will both keep my development branch crisp and clean from any new code not related to me, and it will also squash everything into one commit sort of automatically. I pull request that separate branch, no conflicts assured. Now when finishing I realized that main progressed again , what should I do at that point? I don't want to delete that branch, I already have a pull request on it ( probably with requested changes) ? How do I move it again to the new main, further solving new conflicts?

I tried looking it up but I am afraid I will mess up the PR.

Comment: The pull request will be automatically updated to reflect the difference between your development branch and main.

Comment: Merging is a manual action. If you don't want to merge, just don't do that.

Comment: How do I move it again to the new main location, further solving new conflicts?

Comment: You do what you didn't want to do in the first place, you merge main into it. The issue here is that you have files that multiple people are touching in non-compatible ways. As long as you and your team keeps doing that, you're going to have merge conflicts, there's no way around that. You should try to figure out why you keep doing that, and maybe refactor and isolate some code, so that you don't trip over each other all the time.

Comment: Is my idea bad? How can I then keep my development branch intact?

Answer (score 0):

First step you could maybe identify what is causing the conflicts are you and someone else working on the same tasks hence the many conflicts.